# Zipar mais de 1 arquivo

Tags: java, arquivo-zip

Como posso zipar mais de um arquivo? Só estou conseguindo com apenas um. Esse é o meu código:

```
public static void compactarParaZip(String arqSaida, String arqEntrada)
        throws IOException {
    int cont;
    byte[] dados = new byte[TAMANHO_BUFFER];

    BufferedInputStream origem = null;
    FileInputStream streamDeEntrada = null;
    FileOutputStream destino = null;
    ZipOutputStream saida = null;
    ZipEntry entry = null;

    try {
        destino = new FileOutputStream(new File(arqSaida));
        saida = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(destino));
        File file = new File(arqEntrada);
        streamDeEntrada = new FileInputStream(file);
        origem = new BufferedInputStream(streamDeEntrada, TAMANHO_BUFFER);
        entry = new ZipEntry(file.getName());
        saida.putNextEntry(entry);

        while ((cont = origem.read(dados, 0, TAMANHO_BUFFER)) != -1) {
            saida.write(dados, 0, cont);
        }
        origem.close();
        saida.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Se eu passar mais 2 arquivos como parametro no metodo `compactarParaZip`, o que eu deveria alterar? Tenho como fazer um `Array` do tipo `File`, assim acho que eu conseguiria passar vários arquivos.

Comment: Você quer que o resultado seja somente um arquivo compacto com todos estes passados por parâmetro ou que cada um seja compactado separadamente?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16547340/4056678

Comment: Quero 1 arquivo com todos os outros passados por parâmetro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar de "quebrar" a assinatura de `compactarParaZip`, você pode alterar a assinatura para um [`varargs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html), algo assim:

```
public static void compactarParaZip(final String arqSaida, final String... arqEntradas) throws IOException { }
```

Daí, a implementação poderia ser alterada para alguma coisa parecida com isto:

```
public static void compactarParaZip(final String arqSaida, final String... arqEntradas) throws IOException {
    int cont;
    final byte[] dados = new byte[TAMANHO_BUFFER];

    final FileOutputStream destino = new FileOutputStream(new File(arqSaida));
    final ZipOutputStream saida = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(destino));

    for (final String arqEntrada : arqEntradas) {
        final File file = new File(arqEntrada);
        final FileInputStream streamDeEntrada = new FileInputStream(file);
        final BufferedInputStream origem = new BufferedInputStream(streamDeEntrada, TAMANHO_BUFFER);
        final ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(file.getName());
        saida.putNextEntry(entry);

        while ((cont = origem.read(dados, 0, TAMANHO_BUFFER)) != -1) {
            saida.write(dados, 0, cont);
        }
        origem.close();
    }

    saida.close();
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, consegui.